# Where does the space between the bottom of the picture and the border come from

Tags: html, css

I have this simple image tag which is wrapped by a div. I just don't understand why the div grows larger in height than the image.

**html**

```
<div class="cc-thumbnail-bar-item">
        <img src="http://www.sir-chesterfield.de/media/catalog/product/0/1/01.01.a_4_4.jpg" class="cc-thumbnail-bar-item-image" />
</div>
```

**css**

```
.cc-thumbnail-bar-item {
    border: 1px solid #918e7d;
}

.cc-thumbnail-bar-item-image {
    width: 48px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cburgdorf/YW8Ka/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why an image inside a div has an extra space below the image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: Ah, that explanation makes sense. Crazy I didn't encounter that earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because an image is rendered inline, like a letter. you can see the space at the bottom of the every text.

It can be fixed either by adding `line-height` and `vertical- align`

Add `line-height:0`

```
.cc-thumbnail-bar-item {
     border: 1px solid #918e7d; line-height:0
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YW8Ka/1/)**

Add `vertical-align`

```
.cc-thumbnail-bar-item-image {
    width: 48px; vertical-align:top
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/YW8Ka/4/)**

Comment: That doesn't explain *why*, which is what the question is asking.